# Tab order of post admin page

Tags: admin-menu

When I edit my post and update, I edit a textarea and hit a `Tab` key, then `Update` button will be activated and press `Enter` to admit the change.

But in another environment if I press `tab`, then `preview` button is activated.

Why is this difference of tab order happens? And which tab order is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form fields have something called a tab index. So when you press the tab key it will  know where to go next. However when a page has multiple forms the indexes can get mixed up, unless they are clearly specified in each field.

Some wp form plugins give you the ability to add the form index range, that way if there are multiple form elements in one page they won't overlap.

So to answer your question... the tab order will change from page to page depending on the form elements in it.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)'s some more reading on tab index.